# Book involving small scale spaceships which are used to power an economy?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, warfare

I'm looking for a novel I read whilst at high school 1996-2000. It involves a young child who accidentally discovers the truth behind a stellar war being fought by 'miniature' humans created specifically to fuel the economy of this particular world. If I'm not mistaken the book was one of a series of discreet novels that were linked numerically through their titles.

Another one of the novels involved a dystopian future where Earth had been abandoned by all save toxic mutants. Sorry I know the info is vague but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds really interesting. I am interested in this as well +1

Comment: my first thought, before I noticed you say they were novels, was that they could be a couple of short stories by Philip K Dick - did you read any others? Any idea how old the books were? Length?